# Release all used memory in python

Tags: python, linux, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm using some libraries for training my model in Machine learning but those are using a lot of memory and will not release it after it's done, even with 60 Gb memory I always lack of memory! I know there are some solutions like "del variable gc.collect()". but these methods need to determine which variable we need to remove from memory! it's not possible for me as I have a lot of libraries and variable and I have no idea which one is the problematic. it happens mostly when I'm running my test on Linux, in windows it's not that bad

So my question is, is there any solution to remove or release all the memory used by current application automatically before exit?

Comment: That is strange, you are probably leaving some process around. Can you do `ps aux --sort=-%mem | head` to see the process that is using memory?

Comment: Thank you @Nulo Yes, I believe that's the problem and I was wondering how can I release these memory automatically. there is the output:

ubuntu      4948 1594 13.4 15497872 8316416 pts/4 Rl+ Sep17 63743:11 python trans.py
ubuntu   3358644  241 10.1 16149352 6254912 pts/6 Sl+ Sep19 5368:47 python fesel.py
ubuntu     17243 27.2  8.8 15343136 5441944 pts/2 Tl  Sep17 1077:55 python fesel.py
ubuntu   3358391  579  8.7 12959288 5387956 pts/5 Rl+ Sep19 12892:50 python fesel.py
ubuntu    191105  0.0  6.0 10966668 3727112 pts/5 Tl  Sep18   0:53 python fesel.py

Comment: ubuntu   1922977  0.0  5.9 10715388 3659300 pts/5 Tl  Sep18   1:02 python fesel.py
ubuntu   1923076  0.0  5.7 10619312 3562976 pts/6 Tl  Sep18   0:57 python fesel.py
ubuntu    194228 48.1  4.8 12897800 2997656 pts/6 Tl  Sep18 1696:45 python fesel.py
ubuntu    131606  5.3  4.4 12633348 2734004 pts/3 Tl  Sep18 194:32 python fesel.py

Comment: Two things to notice, the windows and Linux implementations of python are different (different project, different C libraries and compilers) + machine learning models consume a lot of memory, some in the terabytes, so increasing the memory or switching to windows might be what's needed

Comment: What are those python scripts in relation to your model's script?

Comment: Unfortunately my current work place can not afford to get another server so my current Linux is the only option! :| 

these scripts simply run Bert and SVM, its pretty normal for these models to consume a lot of memory but I need to release the used memory

Comment: you seem to have lots of `python fesel.py` hanging around, shouldn't they have finished? If you don't need those you can kill them with `pkill -xf 'python fesel.py'`. But you should see what is happening with that script

Comment: Acctually they are finished, at least in terminal it is. 

 I used "pkill -xf 'python fesel.py'" but still they are hanging around. nothing changed!

Comment: USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
ubuntu      4948 1594 13.3 15439500 8258328 pts/4 Rl+ Sep17 65354:31 python trans.py
ubuntu     17243 26.5  8.8 15343136 5441944 pts/2 Tl  Sep17 1077:55 python fesel.py

Comment: ubuntu    191105  0.0  6.0 10966668 3727112 pts/5 Tl  Sep18   0:53 python fesel.py
ubuntu   1922977  0.0  5.9 10715388 3659300 pts/5 Tl  Sep18   1:02 python fesel.py
ubuntu   1923076  0.0  5.7 10619312 3562976 pts/6 Tl  Sep18   0:57 python fesel.py
ubuntu    194228 46.7  4.8 12897800 2997656 pts/6 Tl  Sep18 1696:45 python fesel.py
ubuntu    131606  5.2  4.4 12633348 2734004 pts/3 Tl  Sep18 194:32 python fesel.py
ubuntu    193691 47.2  4.3 11446144 2673116 pts/3 Tl  Sep18 1712:05 python fesel.py
ubuntu     16840  0.0  3.3 9118804 2062900 pts/3 Tl   Sep17   0:37 python fesel.py